# IIS 10 on Windows Server 2016 becomes slower over time

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, server

We have a prod server running on IIS 10 (Windows Server 2016). The strange thing is, that the response time (even to access the main page) of an HTTP Request becomes slower after some time.

First assumption was that the ASP.NET Server / WCF Services have a problem, but even if we do an IISRESET /Stop - wait 10 secs - IISRESET /Start does not solve the problem.

Only a full restart of the server solves the problem.

[image]

The small red spikes in the picture shows our tries with IISRESET.

Do you have any suggestions on this?

Comment: Stack Overflow won't help much in this case, as more analysis must be done on the server itself. Open a support case via https://support.microsoft.com please.

Comment: I thought someone would have an idea that points me to the right direction ...

Comment: I have the same problem with WS2019 and Aplication .NET, the server is updated SO and Dirvers, WINDOWS activated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem can be solved by improving the configuration of the server, or setting [idle-timeout](https://support.sisense.com/kb/en/article/cancel-iis-timeout-and-recycling).

Please check the CPU and memory usage. If you find that the website has high CPU, please [use the DebugDiag Collection to collect relevant information](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/memory-dumps-to-study-a-high-cpu-performance-issue/ba-p/2556170).